# Doptor, Laravel based framework installation problem

Tags: laravel, content-management-system

Doptor is a laravel 4.2 based cms with fantastic feature. But when I run the commend '$composer install --no-dev' according to the installation procedure of Doptor. I get the following error on console.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
- don't install illuminate/support 5.1.x-dev|install illuminate/support dev-master
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support dev-master
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.2.x-dev
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support 5.0.x-dev
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.17
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.16
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.15
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.14
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.13
- Installation request for mews/captcha dev-master -> satisfiable by mews/captcha[dev-master].
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0-BETA1
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.1
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.10
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.11
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.12
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.2
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.4
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.5
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.6
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.7
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.8
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.9
- mews/captcha dev-master requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.4].
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4
- Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.2.x-dev, v4.2.0, v4.2.0-BETA1, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4,v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
```

The doptor composer.json is

```
{
"name": "doptor/doptor",
"description": "A Laravel Based CMS",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "cms"],
"license": "MIT",

"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "cartalyst/sentry": "2.0.*",
    "robclancy/presenter": "1.2.*",
    "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "~2.1.0",
    "creolab/laravel-modules": "dev-master",
    "intervention/image": "2.*",
    "vespakoen/menu": "2.0.15",
    "guzzle/guzzle": "dev-master",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "*",
    "mews/captcha": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "2.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "1.11.5"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/services",
        "app/presenters",
        "app/services/Validation",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/components",
        "app/components/posts/database/migrations",
        "app/components/ContactManager/Database/Migrations",
        "app/components/ReportBuilder/Database/Migrations",
        "app/components/ReportGenerator/Database/Migrations",
        "app/components/posts/database/seeds"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Modules\\": "app/modules",
        "Components\\": "app/components"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

}

As it is failed to installing composer in package. It shows the following error on browser.

> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\Doptor\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Doptor\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>   Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Doptor\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Doptor\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

I think the problem is conflicting among doptor's dependencies that is hard to spot for me. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is found here: "mews/captcha dev-master requires illuminate/support ~5.0". The master branch for the [mews/captcha](https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha) package has been updated to require Laravel 5.

According to their documentation, the Laravel 4 compatible branch has been moved to `master-l4`. Update your composer file to require `"mews/captcha": "dev-master-l4"`, and see how that works out.

### Edit

*responding to comments*

It looks like the latest commit on the Doptor package (on March 29) broke the dependencies. The `robclancy/presenter` package version `1.2.*` requires Laravel 4.0/4.1, but Doptor updated their project to use Laravel 4.2 without updating the `robclancy/presenter` package to use `1.3.*`.

So, you can try updating the composer file to use `"laravel/framework": "4.2.*"` and `"robclancy/presenter": "1.3.*"`. If that doesn't work, you can try rolling the composer file back to `"laravel/framework": "4.1.*"` and `"robclancy/presenter": "1.2.*"`.

Comment: I change "mews/captcha": "dev-master" to "mews/captcha": "dev-master-l4" and now it takes composer installation good but at last moment of installation it gives the following error
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception \FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Illuminate\View\ Environment' not found","file":"C:\xampp\htdocs\Doptor\vendor\robclancy\presenter\src\Robbo\Presenter\V iew\Environment.php","line":11}} I
In browser It shows 
Class 'Illuminate\View\Environment' not found

Comment: @strangerAshik I have updated my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Thanks @patricus it works for both combination, just have to set key to 16 char at app.php under config.

Comment: @strangerAshik Good to hear. Don't forget to accept the answer so others can know at a glance this fixed the issue.